# AWS Amplify error: (node:68674) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am applying Amplify in Vue.js,
so the issue here is after I've done command successfully :

```
amplify add api
```

then I am trying to do command:

```
amplify push
```

Then below error always there:

> SKY-MacBook-Pro:my-project sky$ amplify push ⠇ Fetching updates to
>   backend environment: mpvue from the cloud.(node:68674)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchKey: The specified key does
>   not exist.
>       at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:816:35)
>       at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
>       at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>       at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
>       at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
>       at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
>       at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
>   (node:68674) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:68674) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. ⠹ Fetching updates to
>   backend environment: mpvue from the cloud. SKY-MacBook-Pro:my-project
>   sky$

Here is the docs for your reference:
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?platform=vue